# How can I add any set of Java Number objects, getting the most accurate result?

Tags: java, numbers

I have to write a SUM() method that can get arrays of Number objects (Java). So it might be several Short objects, then a couple of Floats, then a BigDecimal.

If everything is a Byte/Short/Integer/Long then the returned value should be a Long.

If everything is a Byte/Short/Integer/Long/Float/Double, then the returned value should be a Double.

If there's a BigDecimal in the mix with the above, then the result should be a BigDecimal. And if a BigInteger is in there, then I'm not sure what/how to handle it as each BigInteger can have different values for how large a number it handles.

At present I collect a running total of long (all Byte/Short/Integer/Long), double (all Float/Double) and bigDecimal. Then at the end add into whichever has been used (I have 2 booleans tracking that) and return that.

It works, but it's not clean. Is there an easier way? A way to add two Number objects and it returns the appropriate Number object?

Comment: All of the types you mention can be represented exactly as a `BigDecimal`. I would just convert all the inputs to `BigDecimal` and add. The answer will  be exactly right, rather than just accurate.

Comment: There is not going to be any clean way to do this; Java doesn't intend for you to mix different `Number` types like you're trying to do.

Comment: @PaulBoddington - Without going into the details, there are things we can do if we know it's a Long (ie no decimals) or a Double (don't have to convert from BigDecimal). Plus we want fast performance and most times everything is a long or a double.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no nice way to do this, but you can break it up into a lot of smaller, simpler methods. My approach is to set up a hierarchy of types. Ideally the addition would only involve types with lower ranks. Once you've worked out the appropriate level to do the addition at, you can call the appropriate method. Here is my code (not tested).

```
private static final Map<Class<? extends Number>, Integer> RANKS;

static {
    Map<Class<? extends Number>, Integer> map = new IdentityHashMap<>();
    map.put(Byte.class, 0);
    map.put(Short.class, 1);
    map.put(Integer.class, 2);
    map.put(Long.class, 3);
    map.put(BigInteger.class, 4);
    map.put(Float.class, 5);
    map.put(Double.class, 6);
    map.put(BigDecimal.class, 7);
    RANKS = Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
}

private static Number addBytes(Number... numbers) {
    byte a = 0;
    for (Number number : numbers)
        a += number.byteValue();
    return a;
}

private static Number addShorts(Number... numbers) {
    short a = 0;
    for (Number number : numbers)
        a += number.shortValue();
    return a;
}

private static Number addInts(Number... numbers) {
    int a = 0;
    for (Number number : numbers)
        a += number.intValue();
    return a;
}

private static Number addLongs(Number... numbers) {
    long a = 0;
    for (Number number : numbers)
        a += number.longValue();
    return a;
}

private static Number addBigIntegers(Number... numbers) {
    BigInteger a = BigInteger.ZERO;
    for (Number number : numbers)
        a = a.add(number instanceof BigInteger ? (BigInteger) number : BigInteger.valueOf(number.longValue()));
    return a;
}

private static Number addFloats(Number... numbers) {
    float a = 0;
    for (Number number : numbers)
        a += number.floatValue();
    return a;
}

private static Number addDoubles(Number... numbers) {
    double a = 0;
    for (Number number : numbers)
        a += number.doubleValue();
    return a;
}

private static Number addBigDecimals(Number... numbers) {
    BigDecimal a = BigDecimal.ZERO;
    for (Number number : numbers) {
        a = a.add(
                number instanceof BigDecimal ? (BigDecimal) number
                        : number instanceof BigInteger ? new BigDecimal((BigInteger) number)
                        : new BigDecimal(number.doubleValue()));
    }
    return a;
}

public static Number add(Number... numbers) {
    if (numbers.length == 0)
        return 0;
    int max = -1;
    for (Number number : numbers) {
        Integer rank = RANKS.get(number.getClass());
        if (rank == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        max = Math.max(max, rank);
    }
    switch (max) {
        case 0: return addBytes(numbers);
        case 1: return addShorts(numbers);
        case 2: return addInts(numbers);
        case 3: return addLongs(numbers);
        case 4: return addBigIntegers(numbers);
        case 5: return addFloats(numbers);
        case 6: return addDoubles(numbers);
        case 7: return addBigDecimals(numbers);
        default: throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With your requirement of long/double/BigDecimal return value, there's probably no better way. I'd leave it like that, or just return a BigDecimal - supports all types and sizes. Is there a reason you don't do that?
You could, however, enhance the design a little bit and create some type of Map or enum, giving each type a return type parameter and grant them "strength", to make BigDecimal override Long etc.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a class `Numbers` couple of months ago, which might help you. Have a look at the source-code:

https://github.com/pmeisen/gen-misc/blob/master/src/net/meisen/general/genmisc/types/Numbers.java

In general,

1. you may use the `determineCommonType` method to determine the common type of all the `Number` instances you have
2. you want to cast all the values in your array to that common type using `castToNumber`
3. you add the values using an implementation of add for each possible type (because the `Number` interface does not provide such a method, you have to write it by yourself or use something like `longValue`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html#longValue()).

Of course, it may be also possible to map everything to a `BigDecimal`, and then cast it back to the common type using the appropriate `Number` implementation (e.g. longValue if you want a long).

**Note**:

- The implementation on GitHub does not support all the concrete `Number` implementations (e.g., `AtomicInteger`), but I think it can be easily enhanced.
- Don't forget that summing the values might lead to an overflow, e.g., adding two `Integers` may need to return a `Long`